# Изучаю JavaScript и при запуске кода вкладка выдаёт ошибка out of memory, но памяти хватает

Tags: javascript, javascript-faq

Код всего лишь на 20 строчек и при запуске его выдаёт ошибку об нехватке памяти, у меня 4гб озу ранее такое не наблюдалось, прикладываю фото. И есть ещё один вопрос, если кто понял код то сможете объяснить как первая функция (function) может быть связана с var years? Не понял этот момент, в видео объясняется это но к сожаление я не полностью это понял. Спасибо [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас ошибка в коде

```
for(var i = 0; 1 < arr.length; i++)
```

Поменяйте пожалуйста условие окончания правильно

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
```

Иначе там бесконечный цикл с постоянным добавлением в массив элемента

По второму вопросу ваша функция никак не связана с данным массивом, только передав в параметре массив вы можете связать их в идеале, а так ваш массив объявлен глобально и по сути виден для всех ваших функций.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное, исправил и заработало

Comment: Не вопрос всегда пожалуйста